# Is the following sentence correct?

Tags: syntax

この言葉について私自身の定義を与えるが、今から異なるシナリオを見ましょう。

Is the above sentence good?

I want to say: "I will give my definition about this word, but for now let's look at the different scenarios"

I will derive the definition of this word from the scenarios that I will provide (my intention of the above sentence)

Comment: Perhaps, Description of more detailed situation to this question.

Answer (score 3):

- Don't mix だ/である style and です/ます style.
- Replace 今から (from now) with ひとまず (for now; putting that aside).
- Use も (also; too) instead of を so that you can clarify your intention.
- 見てみましょう (take a look) is better than simple 見ましょう here.
- (optional) 定義を与える sounds like a literal translation. Consider 定義を述べる.

> - この言葉について私自身の定義を述べますが、ひとまず、異なるシナリオも見てみましょう。
> - この言葉について私自身の定義を述べるが、ひとまず、異なるシナリオも見てみよう。

Comment: While I'd agree with the rule "Don't mix だ/である style and です/ます style" in something like a talk, in my understanding it's quite common, or even preferable to not have です/ます all over your sentence and instead only at the end, if it is a mostly informal situation.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie For example `彼の述べた定義を見てみましょう` is perfectly natural. But this one is kind of two independent sentences joined by "が", so 「与えるが、～見てみましょう」 looks weird to me.

Comment: Sorry, I think I actually misread your post! I thought you were saying you should never mix the two styles, but now I see you just meant for this sentence, which I totally agree with (because the rest of the sentence is so formal, even the 「が」 itself). In general though, I see no problem with mixing the styles, like 「今すぐは無理だと思うけど、明日は問題ないですね。」 for example.

Comment: Ahhh... that would be a good answer too. Inserting ひとまず, between, and ”も”, that can make sense.